# ERC-20 converter transaction history

Tags: ethereum, transaction

When Ethereum projects move over to Cardano via the erc20 converter, will their existing transaction history be maintained on the Cardano blockchain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not directly, as the token minted on the Cardano blockchain will be a new asset.

If such an use case is needed, one might use an oracle to see it or metadata to record it at the minting time.